# Finding element with similar id of 2 fields - text could be random, Selection should be based on text exists or not

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Please see the image for better understanding 
[image]

1. My search is by ID (RIN)
2. ID could be either Legal Name (Corporation client) or Last Name (Individual Client)

**Below code works:**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'l_Name')]")).click();` - **This one will click on Legal Name (Working)**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'Last_Name')]")).click();` - **This works for Last Name if the search ID (RIN) is given for Last Name**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'Name')]")).click();` - **This one also works for Legal Name as the first element displayed is Legal Name But not working for Last Name**

If I do

`String S = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'l_Name')]")).getText();
System.out.println(S);`

`KAB GIHADO CARTAGE INC.` - **String is displayed**

**But I want something like this:**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'Name')]"))` --- `(@id,'Name')`where driver identify Legal name or Last name based on if text exists or not - Text will be random based on the ID (RIN)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Based on the ID used in the search, Hyperlink will be available for either Legal Name or Last Name, I want to click on the hyperlink where text is available

Comment: text will be random based on the ID, ID is coming from Data driven from an excel. 
Element identification can be narrowed down to Legal Name or Last Name by using `(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'Name')]")`. But is there a possibility to click if text exists or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the logic that will get the text from the field contains `Name` in it's ID and contains some text (not empty).

```
String S = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'Name')][not(.='')]")).getText();
System.out.println(S);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Just ran the test for both Legal Name and Last name, both scenarios worked.

Comment: worked code `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(@id,'Name')][not(.='')]")).click();`